# Notching Deck Posts That Support Roof

Tags: framing, deck, beam, post

[image]I am in the planning stage of my porch build. It will be a gable covered deck. I would like to use the front corner posts to support the deck and roof. This method will obviously force me to build a flush beam scenario vs the joists resting on top.

My question is, I have been told to notch the post at the deck level to install the beam. If the post is also supporting the roof load, is this a good idea? is there a better approach? I will be using double 2x for the deck beam. The posts are 6x6. the beam and joists are 2x10. You can see in the pic the notch that was recommended.

[image: Porch]

Comment: So what about putting the joist support rails into the posts with tenons?

Comment: You don't have dimensions on your sketch.  But I think you need more than a single 2x10 for your beam that runs between the two posts parallel to the house.

Comment: And for your roof, with what's you've shown you're going to need ceiling rafters to tie the two sides of the porch together and keep the roof from "pancaking".  Or else you're going to need collar ties.  Either approach will distract, at least IMM, the openness of the gabled roof.

Comment: @SteveSh if you zoom in, he does have  a doubled beam between the 2 posts. Also, (I'm no expert here...) it appears that there's a tie between the two posts. If the other end of the "top plates" are attached to the wall of the existing house, it seems to me that should be sufficient, no?

Comment: We can have all sorts of smart and non-smart opinions. What it really comes down to is what your AHJ will issue a permit for. (My intuition is that a non-continuous post holding up a roof isn’t gonna pass review.)

Comment: @Aloysius - Maybe, maybe not.  My covered deck was built that way.  Posts fastened to the footers; beams resting on the posts; joists attached to the beams with hangars (on the outside), and resting on the middle beam; decking installed; then 4x6 posts for the gabled roof.

Comment: Yeah, hurricane zone would require strapping on a joint like that which would limit the finish options. I'd be suprised if anywhere had a continous timber requirement but everywhere is different - definitely agree with checking what is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of challenges with notches and they should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

You need the notch to be cut tight enough so that the timber above isn't unsupported, but also it needs to be considerate to the fact that wood is a natural material that swells and moves around. On top of that structural aspect, a precision notch cut isn't as straight forward as just terminating the post, and then starting a new one on top of the deck, with appropriate metalwork to tie it all off (this will vary depending on your region - i.e. hurricane prone regions will have much stricter requirements).

The most common approach that you'll find is the rim boards are mounted into the side of the post. This alone isn't up to modern codes though as you should (or are possibly required to) add a metalwork seat underneath the rim:

[image]

If your goal is to have an inset rim such that the post is flush with the rim board, the easiest approach is to give the deck itself a double rim joist such that the upper posts are fully supported. Such a doubled up board doesn't have to run the complete length of the deck either - it's quite common for it to be one spacing only. Use post to beam metalwork or strapping connections to tie it all together.

Here's an example build - in this one, "10 - Beam" (rim) is doubled up for the whole length of the deck:

[image: Deck frame sample]

Comment: So I'm clear, you suggest doubling up the rim joist and attaching that on the top of the bottom post. Then using a separate top post to support the roof? See the additional picture it my post.

Comment: @TimPowell Correct - much easier to build (more specifically, much easier to get right). Not as common as mounting the rim to the side of the post but an inset rim gives you a nice flush finish which can be advantageous depending on what your end goal appearance is.

Comment: Also, no matter how tight the beam/joist is when it's first fitted into your "perfect" notch, the wood is going to shrink as it dries (assuming SPF here) and will no longer be a snug fit in the notch over time.

Comment: @TimPowell I re-read your original post and it seems like having an inset rim probably isn't a requirement for you so I've added in some extra info on the common approach and joint detail.

Comment: That image sure seems to show the posts notched out. If done correctly, it's the preferred way to do it, but I wouldn't recommend the "double width" notch in the OP image. Having the rims in notches allows the weight to transfer directly to the posts instead of the hardware. See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/66421/25178

Comment: @gnicko if you think someone can diy a suitable notch cut, feel free to add another answer :) By far the most common thing I've seen is the rim mounted to the side of the post with metalwork underneath it. L Notching the very top of the post for the roof itself would be recommended but is a different joint/ not the one the OP is asking about.